# Draggable legend in matplotlib whilst having event picking functionality

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have created event picking on the legend but I am having difficulty implementing a draggable legend at the same time. The two seem to conflict as the draggable legend does work when removing this line that implements event picking: `self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master

        aveCR = {0:np.array([.582,1.081,1.507,1.872,2.180]),1:np.array([2.876,6.731,1.132,1.305,1.217])}    
        legend = ['A', 'AB']

        plotFrame = tk.Frame(master)
        plotFrame.pack()

        f = plt.Figure()
        self.ax = f.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master=plotFrame)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

        # Plot
        lines = [0] * len(aveCR)
        for i in range(len(aveCR)):        
            X = range(len(aveCR[i]))
            lines[i], = self.ax.plot(X,aveCR[i],label=legend[i])

        # Legend
        leg = self.ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=2, borderaxespad=0.)
        if leg:
            leg.draggable()

        self.lined = dict()
        for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
            legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
            self.lined[legline] = origline

    def onpick(self, event):
        # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
        # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility
        legline = event.artist
        origline = self.lined[legline]
        vis = not origline.get_visible()
        origline.set_visible(vis)
        # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
        # have been toggled
        if vis:
            legline.set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            legline.set_alpha(0.2)
        self.canvas.draw()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("hem")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use a draggable legend, there is of course the possibility that a pick_event occurs on the legend; in fact all pick_event happening on one of the lines inside the legend also happen in the legend.

Now you would want to have the custom picking only happening if the picked artist is one of the lines from the dictionary. You can check for this to happen by querying if the `event.artist` is in the `self.lined` dictionary.

```
    def onpick(self, event):
        if event.artist in self.lined.keys():
            legline = event.artist
            origline = self.lined[legline]
            vis = not origline.get_visible()
            origline.set_visible(vis)
            # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
            # have been toggled
            if vis:
                legline.set_alpha(1.0)
            else:
                legline.set_alpha(0.2)
            self.canvas.draw_idle()
```